# FileSystemWatcher OnError Try/Catch

Tags: c#

Нужно ли мне делать подписку на событие OnError когда мой код в Try/Catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, если хотите видеть ошибки скидываемые в `FileSystemWatcher`. Поймите Ваш

```
try 
{
  var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\path\to\folder");
  ...
}
catch (){
.....
}
```

отловит ошибки создания и инициализации. Все прочие ошибки будут возникать в другом потоке для этого собственно и нужена подписка на событие `OnError`